# Swift Image from URL

Tags: swift, uiimageview

I am trying to display an image from a URL in swift using the code below but nothing appears.

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.psychicliving.co.uk/images/Michael.jpg")
if let data = NSData(contentsOf: url as! URL) {
    cell.imgCarNane.image = UIImage(data: data as Data)
}
```

The odd thing is that if I substitute the image for a jpeg hosted on a different site like:

> https://www.thawte.com/assets/hp/images/promo_myths.jpg

it displays fine.

Is there something about the image I am trying to use that would be causing the issue?

if someone could take a look I would be very greatful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why since the website you're retrieving the image from is using https (and seems secured), but you have to add the website (or allow arbitrary loads) in your plist.

Create an entry App Transport Security Settings https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html

Answer (score 0):

add NSAppTransportSecurity in info.plist

NSAllowsArbitraryLoads= YES

```
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.psychicliving.co.uk/images/Michael.jpg")
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check / try-catch
    imageViewTest.image = UIImage(data: data!)
}
```